# How to exchange a lot of data between mobile devices without going through a server?

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I have two smartphones, one connected by Wi-Fi to home-type router and another connected by 3G data connection.

I need to exchange data between these devices, but this is a lot of data(images) and I wonder if it is possible to do without using a server. The server can be used to exchange data of authentication, but no for images.

[image: Problem description]

I found a solution, consist of creating a socket server in device 1, and pass the device 1 IP by server to device 2, and device 2 uses a socket client. But the problem is that users need to configure router to redirect used port to de device 1, and this is "hard" for them.

Is there any way to improve the proposed solution to not need manipulation router, or some other kind of solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should manipulation be necessary? Or is there any port security applied to the switch ?

Comment: If for example I set the server on port 8080, and called that port with a socket client by the external IP, nothing happens. I have to go into the router configuration panel and set all requests of port 8080 redirect to private address 192.168.0.10 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi** But requires API level 14 or later and it works only for  near devices not for distance one.

Please go through this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: Thanks, but this only allows you to connect devices with Wi-Fi range (100 meters). I need by Internet.

Comment: Then You must use vpn for this.

Comment: I found an Android application (Client 3G - Server Wi-Fi) and don´t asks permission to VPN.